# How can I Stop count down function then running

Tags: jquery

I have this countdown function, but if i want to stop this function while it is in running mode, how can i do that?

```
function GameCounter(){

        var sec = 6
        $("#gamecounter span").html(sec)

        var timer = setInterval(function() { 
            $('#gamecounter span').text(sec--);
            if (sec == -1) {
               newcards();
                    clearInterval(timer);
            } 
        }, 1000);

 }
```

Comment: just use the `clearInterval(timer);` that you have when you want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing that would be,

```
function GameCounter(){ 
        var sec = 6
        $("#gamecounter span").html(sec)
        var timer = setInterval(function() { 
            $('#gamecounter span').text(sec--);
            if (sec == -1) {
               newcards();
                    clearInterval(timer);
            } 
        }, 1000);

        return timer;
 }

 //In the place where you calling the GameCounter() function.
 var timer = GameCounter();
 //Call the below line to stop the interval at any point of time.
 clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: @Kyborek No OP is asking, how do we stop the interval in the middle of its process.